# Is it possible in Java to display a fraction as humans would write it (Unicode)?

Tags: java, math, unicode

Is it possible to display a fraction in the Unicode way with Java?

For example: `3/4 as ¾`

Comment: No, this is impossible.

Comment: You can display it using a horizontal line.

Comment: Only some [fractions](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/mathchart.html#fractions).

Comment: Probably, just take a look at the patterns :p

Comment: This isn't really a Java question it's a question about your display; screen, printer, pdf document or whatever.

Comment: @Jackson I'd say it's a question about unicode, which I would believe is still on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those fractions which have a representation in Unicode, you can of course use a Java program to emit that Unicode symbol. But there is nothing specific about Java here, any programming environment with Unicode display capabilities could do as much. Since the core language of Java doesn't even have a representation for rational numbers, there is no inbuilt conversion, you'd have to code it yourself or find some third-party library to do that for you.